# Visibility of TextView in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, textview, visibility

I have a dialog, which is created with this code:

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(Test.this);
dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
dialog1.setCancelable(true);
...
```

The layout file 'test_layout.xml' contains a typical TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Test" />
```

I want in the code to set this TextView invisible (gone) in some cases.
I tried following:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
tv.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
```

But the TextView still appears in the dialog. If I set in the layout xml file android:visibility="gone" it is not appearing in the dialog. But I need to do it via code.

Here the whole code:

```
    if (whichButton == 1) {

           final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(Test.this);
                                       dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
            dialog1.setCancelable(true);

            TextView tv = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        ...
        dialog1.show();
}
```

Here the whole XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="Name:" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="@string/enterName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Test" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="@string/message" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:maxLength="290"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: This is also not working. The TextView is still visible. Can be the 'final' of Dialog the problem?

Comment: I think the 'final' basically means that you cannot change assignments but shouldn't be an issue with setVisibility() but u could try it once. And incase u r doing this inside a listener and it doesn't let u do it, for the time being make dialog1 a global variable.

Comment: I deleted the final before Dialog dialog1. But it is still not working...I created also a global variable Dialog dialog1, but it still does not work.

Comment: can u show me where u r setting it to invisible? if u can provide that code.

Comment: sure wait a sec, I will post it in the first post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9832/discussion-between-shubhayu-and-tobias)

Comment: can you put your complete xml file

Comment: sure I will do that in the fist post

Comment: Can u put a Log msg to see if the control is entering the (whichbutton == 1) condition?

Comment: it is entering the whichbutton condition, because the dialog is showing up. I have there also a Log.i statement which shows that it called.

Comment: I think I know the problem: the dialog is only created once. Perhaps I have to call beforehand the dialog.remove() method..

Comment: if u cant figure it out, put in the complete related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution or workaround.

The dialog was created in the the onClick method of an AlertDialog.

Now I use the showDialog() method and handle it in the corresponding callback method. 
There it is working fine.

I do not understand why this is working, but I only want to tell other users how they can solve this issue.

I would be happy if someone can come up with a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: this also does not work. And I need to use GONE because I want the space should be also be removed.

Comment: Why do you cast it to your dialog? I mean why do you do this? TextView tv = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);

Use tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_username) instead...

Comment: it alsow does not work with tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_username)

Comment: then it may be because this part of your code is not reachable, what is this if statement for? if (whichButton == 1) , are you setting it to 1 somewhere?

Comment: setting what to 1? whichButton? this is the onDialog listener. It is called, because the dialog shows up.